# Setting DataGridView As Active Control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, focus, keypress

For the project I am working on I have created a very basic virtual keyboard (don't ask me why I am not using the Windows built in one.  The short answer is I **can't**, and I am going to leave it at that).

The way I get the keys on the Keyboard to work, is every editable object, whether it be a TextBox, a part of a DataGridView, etc gains focus, a generic object called `LastFocus` is set to be a reference to that editable object.  Then whenever any of the keys are pressed, the current `ActiveControl` gets set to `LastFocus` and I then call a `SendKeys.SendWait()` call for whatever key was pressed.

My issue at the moment is trying to do this with DataGridView objects.  Right now this is what I have for pressing my 'BACKSPACE' key:

```
Private Sub BtnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    If TypeOf LastFocus Is TextBox Then
        Me.ActiveControl = LastFocus
        SendKeys.SendWait("{BACKSPACE}")
    ElseIf TypeOf LastFocus Is DataGridView Then
        Me.ActiveControl = LastFocus
        SendKeys.SendWait("{BACKSPACE}")
    End If
End Sub
```

The reason I have the sub set up like this is because there are other objects that aren't TextBoxes or DataGridViews that can be set to `LastFocus` that I don't want to get access to the Backspace key.

Running this code however gives me the following error when trying to set `LastFocus` to `ActiveControl` when it is a DataGridView object:

> Invisible of disable control cannot be activated

I am not exactly sure why I am getting this error, as I haven't set the DataGridView to be disabled or anything.  Is there another way I can go about this?

Comment: Does the DataGridView need to be activated then once the backspace btn is pressed? ie - can you add an `if` statement to say if typeof control is a Datagrid then maybe skip over it? Sorry not really an answer, trying to picture how it all works

Comment: I am trying to set it up so that pressing the keys on my keypad simulate typing on a keyboard.  The issue is that when you press the buttons for the Keypad, they gain Focus, so I nee to set the focus back to the previous object that had it.  So if I have a cell in the DataGridView selected, and I press the Backspace Key on my Keypad, I want it to act the same as if I had pressed Backspace on my keyboard

Comment: Ahhh I see, ok so if you set a global of say "LastGoodControl" - then for all the controls that you want it to return back to, add them when they lose the control. I remeber doing something like this for a mini calculator, If I can find it, i'll post my code. Do the users need to type (as in use your keyboard) to send keys to the datagrid or can it be skipped though?

Comment: Is there an event for when an object loses control/focus?  Through my research online I couldn't find one, which is why I have it set up to set my `LastFocus` object when the screen element gains focus.

Comment: Try using focus. See my updated answer .